# Bash script that locates file by known filename variable

Tags: bash

I have a script that loops through hosts, ssh-ing into them and performing some tasks.  One of those tasks, which I haven't been able to script yet, is to cp files from each host to the host where the script runs.  It should only ever cp over one file per day, that file will be in the same location each time and the filename that is generated by a different script incorporates the previous day's date into the filename.  e.g. yesterday's file would be test_2021-03-10.txt.  How would I script finding that file given the info that the filename will always include yesterday's date in that format?  Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps something like that? `scp user@host:/path/to/file/test_$(date --date=yesterday +%Y_%m_%d).txt /path/to/archive/` with GNU `date`.

Comment: I haven't tried your suggestion yet, but I will and reply back.  Thank you.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you very much @M.NejatAydin

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like that?

```
scp user@host:/path/to/file/test_$(date --date=yesterday +%Y_%m_%d).txt /path/to/archive/
```

with GNU date. – M. Nejat Aydin